# Memory Supervision

Tags: android, memory

I want to check the current memory situation to get early informed about low memory.
I called ActivityManager.getMemoryInfo

The strange thing is: MemoryInfo states 77MByte of available memory but next step fails due to allocation of 192KBytes.

Did I something wrong? Or is MemoryInfo useless?

Happend on android 2.3.3

Comment: 77MB isn't allocated to your program. As far as I know, there isn't a way to go over the 16mb (or 24mb) limit for an app's memory usage.

Comment: ? 77mb available = free memory

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MemoryInfo is for debugging.  See my post here on why trying to do things based on "free memory" this way is doomed to failure:

[How do I discover memory usage of my application in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2298208/how-to-discover-memory-usage-of-my-application-in-android/2299813#2299813)